# tkinter GUI only partially updating until mouse is moved

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I've found some unexpected (to me) behaviour in tkinter I'd like to understand a little better.

This is Tcl/Tk 8.6 and Python 3.9.2 on macOS, and the code below creates a very simple window where the Label c is updated by the Radiobuttons a and b.

The unexpected behaviour is this if the 'blueberry' radio button is selected (and so the `Label` is displaying 'blueberry'), and I then click on the 'apple' radio button but do not move the mouse the text 'apple' appears, but with the 'bl' and 'y' of 'blueberry' still visible behind it, and they (and presumably the rest of 'blueberry') only disappear when I move the mouse.

I can easily resolve this aesthetically by simply adding `'sticky=EW'` to the `c.grid()` statement, I assume the text 'blueberry' is actually still there (but now hidden by the label that fills the whole cell) and only disappears again when I move the mouse.

I thought it would be good to understand what is happening here in case I run into situations without such a straightforward solution, and for the general benefit of my programming quality. The closest question I could find on SO is [Tkinter GUI only updates when mouse is moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820795/tkinter-gui-only-updates-when-mouse-is-moved), but I don't think I understand it well enough to know if it's the same behaviour that I'm describing.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.grid()

fruit = StringVar()

a = ttk.Radiobutton(frame, text='apple', variable=fruit, value='apple')
b = ttk.Radiobutton(frame, text='blueberry', variable=fruit, value='blueberry')
c = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=fruit)

a.grid(sticky=W)
b.grid(sticky=W)
c.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: FWIW, the linked question doesn't apply to your code since it's not using threads. Also note that I added a "macos" tag to your question because sometimes that version runs a little differently that it does on other OSs (e.g. I can't reproduce the problem on my computer running Windows).

Comment: Try: `fruit.trace_add('write', root.update_idletasks)` It's still possible that this behaviour will occur sometimes. I have similar experiences and still not sure how to handle it.

Comment: @Atlas435: What OS are you using? I ask because you're workaround should not be necessary (from what I know about how tkinter works).

Comment: @martineau Windows10 but I'm not on a machine and tested that code. But I have similar experiences with canvas and Radiobuttons.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on OSX Big Sur. There's absolutely nothing wrong with your code. If you're seeing visual artifacts, it's probably due to the fast that tkinter has been buggy on OSX for a number of years.

Comment: Thanks for replies (and Martin for edits). Bryan I am also on Big Sur at present (sorry for not having specified in initial post), but certainly happy to chalk this one up to tkinter/OSX bugginess and move on!