tkinter on macos requires mouse movement to operate normally
I have an automated test harness written in python 3.10 for tkinter apps. I wrote a series of tests for a tkinter GUI app and they all run fine and pass on Ubuntu 22.04.
I'm running it on macos Sonoma 14.5 and it sort of works. The tests run with long lags in their operation. If I move my mouse anywhere on the screen (not just in the GUI) then it runs at normal speeds, no lags. All the tests pass, so the test actions are taking place and running correctly, just with lagging

I tried adding .update() and .update_idletasks() in a variety of places. No joy.
I tried adding them for the root window and for individual widgets that were being updated by the test script. No joy.

Note: running the app without the test harness works okay, but then I'm normally moving the mouse around to make that happen so I can't really tell if the mouse movement is "fixing" it or there is some hidden bug in the test harness behavior (again, works fine in Ubuntu)
Not sure what to try next. Any hint or clue would be greatly appreciated.
FYI test harness arch
Test harness has a client-server architecture. The server runs inside the GUI app and waits for an incoming socket connection and commands to run. The client runs in pytest framework to do basic things like: get the current screen content, click a button, get widget content, get widget state (e.g. disabled)

Found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820795/tkinter-gui-only-updates-when-mouse-is-moved?rq=2
The situation here is a little different. The app isn't independently changing, it is responding to actions by the test harness.
Gonna give a shot anyway. fingers crossed.

See Tkinter GUI only updates when mouse is moved
As instructed in the post above, I used the window.after() function to call the test functions on the tkinter thread, rather than the test harness thread and now it works on both macOS and on Ubuntu.
# server class gets requests from individual test cases 
# e.g. cmd='click_left'
class GuiApiServer:
   <snip>
   # this runs in the test harness thread
   def _callback(self, command):
       # all commands sent here should be json
       cmd = json.loads(command)
       # the id should indicate the server thread id
       svc.logger.info(f'server      : callback: cmd={cmd["cmd"]: <10} '
                       f'id={threading.get_ident()}')
       svc.guiapi.run_callback(cmd)


# this class holds all of the test code that interacts with
# tkinter widgets
class GuiApiTinker:
    # this runs in the class that has all of the tkinter window
    # info. self_window is the root window
    def run_callback(self, cmd):
        if self._window is not None:
            # cause the server callback to run under the tkinter thread
            self._window.after(1, svc.server.tkinter_callback, cmd)

# in the server class again 
class GuiApiServer:
   <snip>
   def tkinter_callback(self, cmd, is_invalid):
      # temp code to see how long it takes to get back here
      # when .after() is called
      elapsed = time.time() - self._last_time
      self._last_time = time.time()

      # the id should indicate the tkinter thread id
      svc.logger.info(f'tkinter_cb  : {elapsed: >0.3f}  '
                      f'cmd= {cmd["cmd"]: <10} '
                      f'id={threading.get_ident()}')

      if cmd['cmd'] == 'click_left':
         rsp = svc.guiapi.click_left(cmd)
         self.send(rsp)
      <snip other commands> 

The full code for this is here:
https://bitbucket.org/arrizza-public/gui-api-tkinter/src/master/
See gui_api_tkinter/lib/guiapi/ files for the server side of things.
see sample/ and ver/ for examples of how to use it
